# Java Coordinates Error with array

Tags: java

[image]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {   
   distances[i][j] = haversin(coords[i][0], coords[j][0], coords[i][1], 
   coords[j][1]); distances[j][i] = distances[i][j]; } } long start = 
   System.nanoTime(); int[] shortestPath = nearestNeighbour(distances); double 
   bestShort = 0; for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {bestShort += 
   distances[shortestPath[i] - 1][shortestPath[i + 1] - 1]; } bestShort += 
   distances[shortestPath[size - 1]][shortestPath[0]]; 
}
```

Comment: plz post the codes not images .still same as previous question .no improvement

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
              distances[i][j] = haversin(coords[i][0], coords[j][0], coords[i][1], coords[j][1]);
                distances[j][i] = distances[i][j];
            }
        }
 long start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] shortestPath = nearestNeighbour(distances);
     double bestShort = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {bestShort += distances[shortestPath[i] - 1][shortestPath[i + 1] - 1];
        }
        bestShort += distances[shortestPath[size - 1]][shortestPath[0]];

Comment: Don't put your code in a comment. Put it in the question.

Comment: I have an edit in to add it in the question

Answer (score 0):

plz edit your post and put all your codes not images or one method.
then you have to isolate your operations (to organize and to detect errors):
ex :

`bestShort += distances[shortestPath[i] - 1][shortestPath[i+1]-1];`

to

```
int shortestPath,shortestPath_1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
shortestPath=shortestPath[i] - 1;
shortestPath_1=shortestPath[i + 1] - 1;
bestShort += distances[shortestPath][shortestPath_1];
 }
```

And you should use a debug tool in eclipse to know the source of the problem.
with debug tools you can know what happen and variable values